# Ember not retrieving image assets from Rails backend with paperclip and Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ember.js, docker-compose, paperclip

This is only a problem in production.

I have two Docker hosts, one running an nginx container (serving an Ember app), the other a running a postgres container and a rails-api container.
I want to move the the latter-2 containers onto the first Docker host so they can all be hosted on one and I can delete the second Docker host. The Rails-api uses paperclip to upload photos.

In the Ember app production build I point to the rails backend by adding `ENV.host = 'dockerhost2.com:3000/'` to config/environment.js and `host: ENV.host` in adapters/application.js.

If I keep everything as it is (with 2 docker hosts) everything weirdly works fine -- that is, images are delivered and displayed on the front end. But if I move all containers to one docker host, the images themselves cannot be retrieved and return a 404.

The image URLs are always 'public/system/000/path/to/Image.jpg'. When I keep things separate (on 2 docker hosts) going to 'dockerhost1.com/public/system/000/path/to/Image.jpg' works perfectly though I don't understand why, as the rails app is serving on port 3000 and on a different host. But when I combine all containers onto 1 docker host the same image URLs return 404 and only works when I go to 'dockerhost1.com:3000/public/system/000/path/to/Image.jpg'. This is perplexing.

Locally everything works beautifully when I put all containers onto 1 docker machine and build the Ember app to point to `docker.machine.ip:3000`. Going to 'docker.machine.ip/public/system/000/path/to/Image.jpg' does indeed find the image though, admittedly, I don't understand why.

My Ember docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    image: nginx
    volumes: 
      - ./dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx-site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

My rails docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  sarahdeyong-postgres:
  images:

services:
  rails: &defaults
    build: .
    image: romanhood/sarahdeyong-api:0.0.1
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - images:/myapp/public/system/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    entrypoint: ["bundle", "exec", "rails"]

  server:
    <<: *defaults
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - sarahdeyong-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

and nginx-site.conf:

```
# pushState friendly!
# The setup:
#   * website name is `_`
#   * javascript app is located at `/app`

charset utf-8;

tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay off;
client_header_timeout 10s;
client_body_timeout 10s;
client_max_body_size 128k;
reset_timedout_connection on;

gzip on;
gzip_types
    text/css
    text/javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    application/atom+xml
    font/truetype
    font/opentype
    image/svg+xml;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sarahdeyong;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;


  # To make sure any assets can get through :)
  location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrites;
  }

  # If no asset matches, send it to your javascript app. Hopefully it's a route in the app!
  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
  }
}
```

How can I get my images to retrieve and display properly in my Ember app?

Comment: Just a hunch, maybe specifying a namespace will help? It sounds like it's looking in your Ember app's public folder. To test if that's the case, drop an image in your Ember app at the filepath and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using docker why not use its internal networking feature. I suspect the ember app is having trouble connecting back to localhost/domain1.com because it is referring to the container not the host machine.

Create a docker network and put both containers on it. This virtually connects the containers on a local network. You can then refer to the containers by their name. So in the ember app you just do `name-of-rails-container:3000` to reach it. No need to make port 3000 public on the  rails app either.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/